# Having for loop reference findstr result, moving two lines down to grab variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two codes but part5 is grabbing the wrong variable in a different file than part4.

part4 is using var4, and part5 var5. I want var5 to be grabbed 2 lines down "skip=2 tokens=2 delims==" but for some reason I cannot skip lines when referencing the findstr in part5. Part5 is all that needs changing, part4 is good to go.

**So in essense, How do I get part5 to grab a variable two lines below part4's findstr?**

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

:part4
set var4=
findstr /m "Ship sunk!" "C:\Users\P Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_SCR2\*.clg" "C:\Users\P         Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_SCR2\Log_*.cfg"
if not errorlevel 1 (
for /f "tokens=4 delims==,|" %%D in ('findstr "Ship sunk!" "C:\Users\P Ditty\Documents\SH3       \data\cfg\Backups_SCR2\*.clg" "C:\Users\P Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_SCR2\Log_*.cfg"') do (
set var4=!var4!%%D
 goto :eof
)
)

:part5
findstr "Ship sunk!" "C:\Users\P Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_SCR2\*.clg" "C:\Users\P  Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_SCR2\Log_*.cfg"
if not errorlevel 1 (
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2 delims==" %%E in ('findstr "Ship sunk!" "C:\Users\P Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_SCR2\*.clg" "C:\Users\P Ditty\Documents\SH3\data\cfg\Backups_SCR2\Log_*.cfg"')  do     (
set var5=
set var5=!var5!%%E
goto :eof
)
)
```

Example:

If part4 found "ship sunk!" in this file (Ship sunk! is on first line):

```
asdfasfdasdfShip sunk! asdfjaslkjf;ajfa;
aksdfjklasjflk; fnwerawra
Date=19400112
```

I'd like part5 to make variable of 19400112 (third line after "Date="). The part that is after "Date=" two lines below the part4 variable

Comment: ***Always*** indent your code.

Comment: Please add a sample of the contents of the file and the results you are expecting. It isn't clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't completely understand your code, I can see these details on it:

- In part4 you execute `findstr` first just to know if the target text exist in the file(s), and then execute it again to get certain data (I don't fathom out *what* data is this). You may execute `findstr` just one time to achieve both tasks.
- You said that you want part5 grab a line two lines **below part4's findstr**, but you have NOT connected the result of part4 inside part5 in any way! The `"skip=2` in part5 have NO relation with part4's findstr (skip=2 with respect to what? The default is the first line). You need to get a *line number* from part4 and then use it as "skip=" in part5 with an additional "+2 lines", that is, "+1 skip".

The Batch file below achieve this process on your example data file:

```
@echo off
:part4
set var4=
rem Get the LINE NUMBER where the findstr happen
for /f "tokens=1 delims=:" %%D in ('findstr /N "Ship sunk!" "inputFile.txt"') do (
   set var4=%%D
)
:part5
rem Get the number of two lines below (that is, skip=line+1)
set /A skip=var4+1
rem If text found in part4
if defined var4 (
   rem Get that line from the file (NOT from findstr)
   for /f "skip=%skip% tokens=2 delims==" %%E in (inputFile.txt) do (
      set var5=%%E
      goto continue
   )
)
:continue
echo %var5%
```

Antonio